# reduction from ALLTM to ETM

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability, proof-techniques

I am trying to understand why this "proof" of ETM undecidability is wrong.

ALLTM={ < M >|M is a TM, L(M)=∑*}

ETM={< M >|M is a TM, L(M)=∅}

We know that ALLTM is undecidable, lets assume ETM is decidable (T is a TM that decides ETM) and get a contradiction.

```
 S= "On input < M >, M is a TM:

  1.Construct the following TM M1,

   M1=" On input x:

    1.Run M on x, if M accepts x, reject. otherwise, accept x."

    2.Run T on input < M1 >.

    3.If T accepts, accept, if T rejects, reject.
```

If ETM is decidable, ALLTM is decidable => ETM is undecidable.

Why this reduction doesn't prove that ETM is undecidable?

Comment: The only problem that I see (apart from formatting) is that $T$ is undefined. I think you want to let $T$ be a Turing machine that decides ETM.

Comment: It's part of the proof, I've added it.

Comment: The proof seems fine , can you tell us why you believe it is incorrect or whether is is stated somewhere that this proof is incorrect ?

Comment: It's part of our course material, and was presented as a fact. I thought that there maybe a problem reducing from and to an unrecognized language but I can't find any reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line "If M accepts $x$, reject. Otherwise, accept $x$."   You can't check to see if a machine rejects $x$ and then react accordingly, because some machines reject by *looping forever* (!). The broader consequence of this is you can't take the complement of a Turing machine.

That's a shame because if you could convert a machine $M$ into another machine $M^\prime$ which accepts all of the strings that $M$ rejects and vice-versa, you could show the reduction between $\mathsf{ALL}_\mathsf{TM}$ and $\mathsf{EMPTY}_\mathsf{TM}$ rather easily.

Instead, you need a different approach to prove that $\mathsf{EMPTY_{TM}}$ is undecidable.

---

Here's a different reduction, this time from the halting problem.

1. Given a TM $M$ and a word $w$, construct the machine $M^\prime$ which, on input $x$, simulates $M$ on $w$ for $\mathsf{length}(x)$ steps and accepts if and only if the simulation finishes with accept.
2. Now, if $M$ eventually accepts $w$, then $M^\prime$ accepts some sufficiently long strings. If $M$ rejects $w$, then $M^\prime$ doesn't accept any strings.
3. So if you can decide whether $M^\prime$ is empty, you can decide whether $M$ accepts $w$. But acceptance is undecidable, therefore emptiness is undecidable.